# Unable to use Turi Create in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, turi-create

I installed Jupyter notebook and TuriCreate and then i imported Turicreate in jupyter notebook. after that to use turicreate i wrote :

```
sf = turicreate.SFrame('people-example.csv')`
```

(people-example.csv is a file i wanted to use)
but it showed this error :

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bcf297396ba4> in <module>
----> 1 sf = turicreate.SFrame('people-example.csv')

NameError: name 'turicreate' is not defined
```

Please help me with this.
Thankyou.

Comment: do you use any type of virtual environment??

Comment: You could try running !pip install turicreate in the notebook to see if it imports ok, but I agree that the question is into what environment did you install turicreate vs. what the notebook is running in.  Also, did the install actually work or were there errors?

Comment: Yes first i installed virtual enviroment through ubuntu LTS 18.04 after creating the virtual enviroment , i installed turicreate and jupyter notebook in the same virtual enviroment

Comment: I used the same method given here : https://medium.com/@pam.thumbela/installing-turicreate-on-windows-10-534e147a4792

Comment: after installing jupyter notebook i got this error though :                                             
Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start "file:///home/purple_tulip/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserve ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Answer (score -2):

To resolve this error you need to import turicreate first.
To import turicreate use the following command:

```
    import turicreate as tc
```